# C# opening Excel: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

Tags: c#, excel

In my app I need to open an existing Excel file to write/rewrite some data in rows.

Using VS Express 2015, making a Windows Form App.

When I run the app and click on the button that should open, write and close Excel, I got this:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in
>   WindowsFormsApplication2.exe Additional information: Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

It points to the line in the code which should open the Excel file.

```
 // Open EXCEL
       Excel.Application EXCEL = new Excel.Application();
       string path = "D:\\profily.xls";
        Excel.Workbook Wbook = EXCEL.Workbooks.Open(path , 0, false, 2, "", "", false, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true, false, false); // THERE IS PROBLEM
      Excel.Worksheet Sheet;
```

Comment: Everything after the path is optional, maybe you can debug by stripping the open command down to the path only and then add params in one by one.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause of this is that you are trying to write too much data to the `xls` file. Whether that's too much data to a single cell ([source](http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/101631-why-do-i-receive-an-error-error-code-0x800a03ec-when-using-xlswrite-in-matlab)) or too much data to the file as a whole ([source](http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/115200-error-code-0x800a03ec-when-using-xlswrite)) I don't know.

If you change to reading/writing the newer `xlsx` file format you should avoid these problems.

Answer (score -1):

Rename your your file name **D:\profily.xlsx**

The main difference between these two file extensions is that the XLS is created on the version of Excel prior to 2007 while XLSX is created on the version of Excel 2007 and onward. They are also different on the basis of information storing way. XLS is a binary format while that XLSX is Open XML format.

Comment: changing from xls to xlsx didn´t help. Problem may be in version, got only 1.6.0.0 but cant find 14.0.0 for download